# semantic web - jena sparql

Tags: sparql, jena

After excecuting a query in sparql jena, I tried to get the query result as a list, so I used this:

```
res = ResultSetFormatter.toList(results);
```

but when I write this method before that method the variable `res` returns null.

```
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results);
res = ResultSetFormatter.toList(results);
```

I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Both answers from Jeen and MikeJ below are correct. If you want to make a ResultSet rewindable you can use: ResultSetRewindable results = ResultSetFactory.makeRewindable(res); and call results.reset() when you need to rewind it to use it again. I suggest you do this only with small ResultSet since it will need to be kept in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say `ResultSetFormatter.out(ResultSet)` consumes the `ResultSet`. So after this method has completed, `ResultSet` is empty.

It's somewhat comparable to how an `Iterator` works: once you've iterated over all the elements, the iterator is empty.

Answer (score 3):

The main `ResultSet` implementation is `com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.ResultSetStream` which can only be used once, whereas you are trying to use it twice. The API [documentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/engine/ResultSetStream.html) for `ResultSetStream` says:

> The main ResultSet implementation for returning results from queries.
>   This version is "use once" - you can not reset the result set because
>   the results of the query are not remembered so as not to consume
>   potentially large amounts of memory.